# How does lookup in hash tables that use chaining work?

Tags: algorithm, hashtable

In the hash table below, collisions are handled by chaining. The hash function simply calculates  `%7` on the input value and uses that as the index. Hence 50, 85 and 92 all end up having the same key. 
[image: 1]]

If collisions are handled using linked lists, and my different keys resolve to the same index, how does the lookup algorithm know what value to return?

For example, if a phone book is implemented using hash tables with separate chaining and `A` and `B` resolve to same index, how will the algorithm deduce whose phone number to return?

Comment: Quite easy: You need to do a linear search on the linked list. Therefore, in the worst case, hashing with chaining would have complexity O(N). That would happen if all values in the hash table were mapped to the same index (which a reasonable hash function would try to avoid of course).

Comment: The linked list nodes contain the keys as well as the values.  It just searches the list until it finds the matching key.

Comment: @MattTimmermans So if I were to write a hash function and decided to resolve collisions using secondary hash tables at each index that witnesses a collision instead of a linked list to improve search times, would that be a good idea?

Comment: @andreee So if I were to write a hash function and decided to resolve collisions using secondary hash tables at each index that witnesses a collision instead of a linked list to improve search times, would that be a good idea?

Comment: This sounds like you're trying to implement something similar to [Cuckoo Hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Cuckoo_hashing), but there are many ways to handle collisions, so I suggest you read through the Wikipedia article. Just for completeness, there is also [perfect hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function), which is suitable for a certain range of problems. There's even a [GNU](https://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/) implementation of it :-)

Comment: @andreee Thanks. I'll look into these links

Comment: I still dont know how to search a string value in hash table, with value is number I can convert it to index but how about string?